# Helper class cannot be found by autoloader in my Zend Framework application

Tags: zend-framework, helper

I have the problem that in my ZF App the action helper cannot be loaded. The error message is:

Action Helper by name Sunshine not found

The layout of my ZF app uses modules where I have the following structure:

```
application
   modules
      weather
          controllers
             helpers
```

I have registered the helper in the modules Bootstrap which is located in

```
application -> modules -> weather -> Bootstrap.php
```

Here is the code

```
<?php
class Weather_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initActionHelperBrokers()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath('controllers/helpers', 'Weather_Controllers_Action_Helper_');
    }
}


<?php
class Weather_Controller_Action_Helper_Sunshine extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract 
{

    public function getSunrise() 
    {
        return "06:00";
    }

}

<?php
class Weather_ForecastsController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    protected function getForecasts($date) 
    {
        $sunrise = $this->_helper->Sunshine->getSunrise();
        // tbc
    }
```

What is it, what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: As suggested I tried to add the helper in the bootstrap with the full path, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

the `addPath` method expects the entire path to the helper directory. Change it to something like:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/weather/controllers/helpers', 'Weather_Controllers_Action_Helper_');
```

Alternatively, you can also add the paths via your application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Weather_Controllers_Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/weather/controllers/helpers"
```

Comment: Hm, I tried it with the full path, but the result was the same. What else can be wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the path is actually registered in the helperBroker. Add `Zend_Debug::dump($this->_helper)` to your `getForecasts()` method and check if the path is registered (and is correct)

Comment: I found out that the module bootstrap is not executed. I placed the addPath method to the general bootstrap und stepped into it with the debugger to make sure it is actually executed. And it is. So I got the debug message, but although I have seen the path is correctly added to the plugin registry it is not shown in the debug message somewhere.

Comment: I found the problem, it was a stupid typo (missed a letter in a class name). Also, the problem not loading the modules bootsraps was a result of a missing empty array for the modules in the application.ini (resources.modules[] = "").